# Ubuntu 14.04 loads to black screen with blanking crusor - startx from tty1 fails

Tags: boot, ubuntu-14.04

I really need your help on finding out what can I do with this problem.
I found some "fixes" online but none of them was helpful. I am kind of new to Ubuntu (and linux in general). If I am missing something that can help you figure it out - tell me and I will upload it.

This is the screen I get when i am trying to run startx from the terminal:

[image: Screen]

And [this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aiA4ZQVK) is the log file (Xorg.0).

Comment: I can't inline the screenshot because its not a link to a specific image.  Did it ever work?  Because the only time I have had this problem was when it was a driver problem.

Comment: yeah, it worked great.
i think it happened just after a small update of some packages.

thanks SEARAS for the edit, a lot better like this